# Running an async function in a React return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

I'm trying to display the users name from a firebase db within a react return function.

I have a function called `getUserName` which retrieves the username from the db and returns it.

```
const getUserName = async () => {
        try {
            const docRef = doc(db, "users/" + auth.currentUser?.uid);
            const userDocument = await getDoc(docRef);
            const userData = userDocument.data() as UserData;
            const userName = userData.name.split(' ')[0];
            return userName;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            return "Failed to Retrieve UserName";
        };
    }
```

Then I'm trying to display it in the react component's return.

```
return (
  <div>
    Hi, {getUserName()}!
  </div>
)
```

But I'm getting this error:
`Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322) const getUserName: () => Promise<string>`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm using TypeScript so do I need to specify the type somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

the error info is pretty clear.
to fix this, you can modify the `getUserName` function to use the `useState` hook to store the `username` and update it asynchronously.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserName = async () => {
      try {
        // some code here
        setUserName(userName);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setUserName("Failed to Retrieve UserName");
      }
    };
    getUserName();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Hi, {userName}!
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting the API call into a `React.useEffect()` and storing it in state. React expects a `ReactNode` as indicated in the error, but your function is returning a promise (via `async`). React does not resolve it in the return statement.

```js
function functionalComponent() {
 const [username, setUsername] = getState('foo');

 useEffect(() => {
  // async IIFE
  (async () => {
   const username = await db.getUsername();
   setUsername(username);
  })();
 }, []); // <- Indicates to run this once on mount

 return <>{username}</>;
}
```

Comment: The issue now is that it only works when doing a hot reload. If I refresh the page the returned username is blank because it hasn't been able to fetch the document.